# jquery selector for finding string

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(function(){
    var one = 'twitter';
    var two = 'about';
    var three = 'contact';
    var four = 'exp';
    var five = 'price';

    $('#twitter').hover(function(){
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext" id="twitterz">'+ one + '</p>');
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'1.7em',
                          bottom: '0.1em'});

    }, function(){
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });
    $('#about').hover(function(){
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">' + two + '</p>');
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'1.7em', bottom:'0.1em'});
    }, function(){
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });
    $('#contact').hover(function(){
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">'+ three + '</p>')
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'1.2em', bottom:'0.1em'});
    }, function(){
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });
    $('#experience').hover(function(){
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">'+ four + '</p>');
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'2.3em', bottom:'0.1em'});
    }, function(){
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });
    $('#prices').hover(function(){
        $(this).append('<p class="hvtext">'+ five + '</p>');
        $('.hvtext').css({left:'2em',bottom:'0.1em'});
    }, function(){
        $('.hvtext').hide();
    });

    one.click(function(){
        alert('element exists');
    });



});
```

I'm trying to find a way of calling the `.hvtext` class as a selector which will be later used as an on click event.

**Problem is**, the class is added dynamically by `.append`, i tried using `.is(':visible')` and couldn't find it?

**Another problem**: since it's a class I also want to identify them individually, should i just use Id's?

**To solve this I tried** to distinguish them by adding a `var` for each of the texts hoping I could call them later as an event, but since they're just variable strings and not an element I can't.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: why can't people use carriage returns......

Comment: woops, thanks liam :D

Comment: I don't understand this part: "I'm trying to find a way of calling the .hvtext"  Where in your code are you stuck? I see many $('.hvtext') so please clarify your question. BTW, if it's only for styling, then use CSS rules

Comment: In your specific example, you are setting "one" as a string, which has no click binding. If your actual code reflects this same error, then you should actually use `$('#' + one).on('click', function() {/* code */});`

Comment: Is there any reason you can't write the .hvtext element in your markup and only select/change it in js?

Comment: ah, so .hvtext was the class I appended - when you hover over the div's "#twitter" "#about" etc the '.hvtext' that I appended shows up. I'm stuck with this because it's a problem when i want to single out one of them, because theres 5 of them. It's fine for just a hover but I want to be able to call it later individually, which is why I thought I should use ID's but it becomes kinda messy

Comment: so use some kind of context, e.g: `$(this).find('.hover')...` Or instead of append() use appendTo() to keep chaining on element: `$('<p class="hvtext">' + two + '</p>').appendTo(this).css({...})` Again, if its only for styling, you should use CSS rules declared in CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem is, the class is added dynamically by .append

If it's added dynamically you need to use `.on`:

```
$('#prices').on('click', '.hvtext', function() {/*click stuff here*/});
```

> since it's a class I also want to identify them individually, should i
>   just use Id's?

why? this is where `$(this)` comes in. If you need to pass data I'd do something like:

```
$('#experience').hover(function(){
    var newHvText = $('<p class="hvtext">'+ four + '</p>');
    newHvText.data('leftEm', '2em');
    $(this).append(newHvText);
}, function(){
    $('.hvtext').hide();
}););
```

then

```
$('#prices').on('click', '.hvtext', function() {/*click stuff here*/
       var thisIsTheClickedElement =  $(this);
       var leftEm = thisIsTheClickedElement.data('leftEm');
       $('.hvtext').css({left:leftEm});
});
```

---

You seem to be trying to add a tooltip here, have you considered the http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ instead?

Comment: Added some more detail as it seems you need to adjust the left and bottom depending on which is hovered.